# Symfony2 - One ManyToOne relation on one field referencing two entities

Tags: symfony, relationship

I have an entity which stores "removal requests" to either studios or models. An object (Studio or model can have many requests).

Entity RemovalRequest has a field named : object.

I would like to know if it's possible to do something like this in RemovalRequest entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\GestionBundle\Entity\Studio", inversedBy="requests")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\GestionBundle\Entity\Model", inversedBy="requests")
 */
private $object;
```

I can't find anything about this special case over Internet..

If it's not possible, I'm open to any suggestions you might have !

Comment: /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Studio", inversedBy="requests")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="xx_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */[http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you realy need a new entity to store information about removal? Maybe just add a flag to Studio and Model:

```
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="is_to_remove", type="boolean")
    */
    $isToRemove = false;
```

If you need RemovalRequest entity you should add two properties fore each type like this:

```
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\GestionBundle\Entity\Model", inversedBy="requests")
    */
    $model;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\GestionBundle\Entity\Studio", inversedBy="requests")
    */
    $studio;
```

It is bed idea to store two different classes in one property

Comment: I'll use your second solution because I also have to list every requests in admin part whatever the object type.

Thanks for your response